# Passing a subarray of allocatable array to a subroutine, with right bounds

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine, sub-array, allocatable-array

In the parallel program I'm writing, I defined a lot of multidimensional `allocatable` arrays (actually just 1D, 2D or 3D) which are allocated with **negative lower bounds** during the execution.
The reason why I did that is that each process handles, in a *2D* example, a *14 by 14* `A` matrix and shares an overlap of *2* layers with the *four* neighboring processes, so the matrix is allocated with bounds *`(-1:12,-1:12)`*, where the "internal" part of the matrix corresponds to indices from 1 to *10*. (Italic represent choice/input dependency).

The problem is that in doing this I didn't realize that it would have been impossible to rely on [this Fortran2003 feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537974/fortran-passing-allocatable-arrays-to-a-subroutine-with-right-bounds), thus making impossible to `call mysub(A(:,i),...)` in the caller unit and refer to the dummy counterpart of `A` in the subroutine using the actual bounds (*-1* and *12*), since `A(:,i)` is an expression, and not just a variable.

The problem is solved if I pass the whole array `A` to the subroutine, as explained in the [previous linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538225/5825294), but this would force me to write a "bigger" and less universal subroutine, which, on the contrary, is meant to act on one-dimensional subarrays.

Is it possible to pass a subarray of an `allocatable` array (e.g. `A(:,1)`) to a subroutine in a way that the subroutine is aware of the bounds of the actual variable?

Comment: Essentially: yes, there are ways (such as passing the bounds also and making the dummy explicitly shaped).  However, which is appropriate here may require a little more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know: no, it is not possible.

Be aware that very often, you *do not* want to care about the actual lower bound of an array in a subroutine. If you have a subroutine that sums an array or something similar, you just want to loop from 1 to the size of the array. And you want to be able to pass any arrays to such subroutines.

If you need to start from a specific index in a subroutine you can always

1.
Declare the lower bound as a magic constant

```
real, intent(inout) :: array(-1:,-1:,-1:)
```

Maybe not too nice, but I use it in my main production code because I started it that way years ago.

2.
Declare the lower bound as a constant in a module and use that

```
 use contants

 real, intent(inout) :: array(lb:,lb:,lb:)
```

3.
Pass the lower bound as a dummy argument

```
integer, intent(in) :: lb
real, intent(inout) :: array(lb:,lb:,lb:)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I haven't used your solution yet, but I can accept it, since I think the point 2. is a quite good answer! Thank you